# Issues with iOS 5.1 (9B176) SDK in xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode4.2, ios

When I connect my iPad and it brings up Xcode, there is a message saying:

The version of iOS on “iPad” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

OS Installed on iPad
5.1 (9B176)

Xcode Supported iOS Versions
Latest
5.0 (9A334)
4.3
4.2
3.2.2
3.2.1
3.2
3.1.3
3.1.2
3.1.1
3.1
3.0.1
3.0

Any ideas what is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you go to organizer and click on devices then click on "Use this device for development" it will pull all of the proper symbols for the new iOS version.  You can also delete your derived data and re-connect the device and repeat the above if there is a problem with corrupt symbols.

Comment: Right, I did add it for development and this is the message that showed up after that.  How would I delete the derived data and re-connect the device?

Comment: Here is a little tutorial on how to delete derived data: http://programmersweb.blogspot.com/2011/05/clearing-xcode-4s-derived-data.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to Xcode 4.3 to test it on your device, there is really no other way around that unfortunately. You should be able to run on your simulator though.

Answer (score -1):

You need Xcode 4.3.1, which has iOS SDK 5.1 included. Your current version of Xcode has support for only iOS SDK 5.0 (and below). Your device has iOS SDK 5.1, so your version of Xcode (4.2) doesn't know how to use it. This doesn't mean you cannot continue to use Xcode 4.2 for development and simulator work. You just cannot put anything you create using Xcode 4.2 on your iOS 5.1 device.

Best to upgrade Xcode and stay current, in my view, however. Xcode 4.3.1 is available only via the Mac App Store and you will have to be running Lion.

Comment: I actually have to use Xcode 4.2, I am using Appcelerator development tools.  Is there anyway I can downgrade the iPad iOS SDK to 5.0?

Comment: You might be able to get the 5.0 iOS binary from Apple's developer site, but I am not sure. And then, I am not sure what the procedure would be to downgrade. My understanding is that iOS is not meant to be downgraded, once upgraded... I could be wrong about that though. I am not familiar with Appcelerator; do they have an iOS 5.1 compatible library available (or coming soon)? That would be the best solution.